# Use a different fixed type for interfaces defined in the base class for subclasses

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, mypy

I have a `BaseList` container that takes `BaseItem`'s as items. I then derive a new list `CustomList` and I want it to hold `CustomItem`'s.

How to I type methods in `BaseList` many methods to accept `BaseItem`. And also tell it to use `CustomItem` the derived list `CustomList`?

Here is the code I have so far:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List, Union, Iterator, overload


class BaseItem:
    pass


class BaseList:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.items: List[BaseItem] = []

    def add_item(self, item: BaseItem) -> None:
        self.items.append(item)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[BaseItem]:
        return iter(self.items)


class CustomItem(BaseItem):
    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value: int = value


class CustomList(BaseList):
    def sum(self) -> int:
        # mypy error: "BaseItem" has no attribute "value"
        return sum(item.value for item in self)
```

```py
# no error, but it should say: incompatible type; expected "CustomItem".
CustomList().add_item(BaseItem())

container = CustomList()
container.add_item(CustomItem(10))
for item in container:
    # mypy error: `"BaseItem" has no attribute "value"`
    print(item.value)
```

#### Question

How can I define a type `A` and say in `BaseList` it should resolve to `BaseItem` and in `CustomList` it should resolve to `CustomItem`?

#### Tried so far

I tried using TypeVar with the bounds attribute, but I didn't seem to get it work.

#### Constraints

I have more than just one subclass so I don't want to re-implement all these methods with different types. Also there are many more of these methods with similar problems, like `__contains__`, `__getitem__`, class specific items, etc.

The type hints should be also resolved by PyCharm, as the goal is to get correct code-complete there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make BaseList class Generic:

```
class BaseItem:
    pass


T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseItem)


class BaseList(Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.items: List[T] = []

    def add_item(self, item: T) -> None:
        self.items.append(item)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        return iter(self.items)


class CustomItem(BaseItem):

    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value: int = value


class CustomList(BaseList[CustomItem]):

    def sum(self) -> int:
        reveal_type(self.items)  # Mypy: Revealed type is "builtins.list[CustomItem*]"
        return sum(item.value for item in self)
```